# Ошибка в релиз apk-файле

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Залил я релиз апк. В дебаге всё работало и работает, а вот в релизе выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

И вылетает приложение.
Выдаёт ошибку на самом первом этапе - этапе входа, либо регистрации.

Comment: Полный стак трейс, а так смотрите как вы подключаете драйвер. Возможно вы передаете null в вызываемую функцию

Comment: Это единственная ошибка. Ниже уже идёт описание что и в каких классах пошло не так(ясное дело, что при получении данных).